# POSTing a new item to a SharePoint list using the MS Graph API with a People field

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have set up a React web app consuming data using Microsoft Graph from SharePoint Online which is working well. I can read and write to SP Lists, but I am unable to find any documentation regarding how to structure the data to write into a 'People/Group' field.

Querying a list with these fields yields `"ManagerLookupId": "12"`, where `Manager` is the People Picker field name. I can resolve the `"12"` by using the expand query string. I can't figure out how to write to it using either the `/v1.0` or `/beta` endpoints from Microsoft Graph

Posting this object to the relevant endpoint works (for Single Line Text, Choice, etc).

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "a",
    "Category": "b",
    "Description": "c"
  }
}
```

But if I were to add in the People picker field, I don't know how to structure that data. I have tried email address and GUID, both of which didn't work. Looking at how SP does it natively, it appears to submit this value on submission for the people picker field (have replaced real values) -

```
{
  "Key": "i:0#.f|membership|EMAIL",
  "DisplayText": "NAME",
  "IsResolved": true,
  "Description": "EMAIL",
  "EntityType": "User",
  "EntityData": {
    "IsAltSecIdPresent": "False",
    "Title": "POSITION",
    "Email": "EMAIL",
    "MobilePhone": "",
    "ObjectId": "GUID",
    "Department": ""
  },
  "MultipleMatches": [],
  "ProviderName": "Tenant",
  "ProviderDisplayName": "Tenant"
}
```

Replicating this also fails to update the People field in the list.

I wasn't able to find any documentation on the MS Graph API site or similar previous questions on their Github, so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find *some* information about this in the documentation for [`FieldValueSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fieldvalueset?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> Lookup fields (like `Author` above) are not returned by default. Instead, the server returns a 'LookupId' field (like `AuthorLookupId` above) referencing the `listItem` targeted in the lookup. The name of the 'LookupId' field is the original field name followed by LookupId.

Under the covers, this is a side-effect of how SharePoint tracks users. As an artifact of history, SharePoint maintains it's own User database. While there was a point in time when SP Admins had a lot of exposure to these users, today it's a fully automated process. It simply creates a new `SPUser` record the first time it sees an authenticated AAD User. These User records have their own `id` property. This is a common `INT` rather than a `GUID` (in your example, their `id` is `12`).

When you're updating a `ListItem`, you need to use SharePoint's `id`. You can pass this as a single value or as an array:

```
{
  "fields": {
     "ManagerLookupId": 12
  }
}

{
  "fields": {
     "ManagerLookupId": [10,11,12]
  }
}
```

Here is the rub, there is no way to obtain this SharePoint User `id` from Microsoft Graph. Obviously, this makes it really challenging to create/update a `ListItem`. To get around this, you can use the old [SharePoint REST API's `ensureUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245233(v=office.15)) endpoint:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/ensureUser(logonName)
```

Keep in mind, you'll also need a token for SharePoint to call this API. If you're using the AAD v1 Endpoint, this is generally just a matter of refreshing your token using your SharePoint resource (`https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com`) for this call and then refreshing back to the Graph resource (`https://graph.microsoft.com`) for your other calls.

Comment: Thanks Marc - that settles what I was suspecting given the low value LookupIds. A bit frustrating that it is not yet available using the Graph API. I really appreciate your time to explain the background!

Do you know whether there it is a on a roadmap for perhaps the beta endpoint so that another API does not need to be called and the associated client based negotiation of making new users, then transferring those ``INTs`` back to the original POST.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I've run into, and complained about, this quite a few times over the years (which is sadly also why I could that much background).

Answer (score 0):

My test demo, User is people field allow multiple users.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "test",
    "UserLookupId@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)",
    "UserLookupId":[10,23]
  }
}
```

For one user.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "test",
    "UserLookupId@odata.type": "Edm.Int32",
    "UserLookupId":23
  }
}
```